# Unable to mount USB flash drive on OpenBSD

Tags: mount, usb-drive, openbsd

My machine on which was installed OpenBSD 5.7-stable, was booted up with my USB 2.0 flash drive plugged into a USB 2.0 port.

I logged in as root, opened up a terminal and typed:

```
mount /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb0
```

The error message was:

```
mount_msdos: /dev/sd1i on /mnt/usb0 : Inappropriate file type or format
```

I tried to reformat the flash drive under each of the following scenarios:

1. The USB stick was formatted as ext2 on a Ubuntu machine using gparted
2. The same stick was formatted as fat32 on the same Ubuntu machine using gparted
3. It was formatted as fat32 on a Microsoft Windows 7 machine

I decided to add the following relevant details to help in your diagnostics. They are the result of a **dmesg** command that I issued:

```
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Apacer 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 30489408 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdb: sdb1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
```

Note: The USB drive as formatted with a FAT32 filesystem using gparted on a Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the filesystem when mouting. Try

`mount -t vfat /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb0`

If you're format is fat32,

`mount -t ext2 /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb0`

if it is ext2

Comment: The USB flash drive is FAT32-formatted. `mount -t vfat /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb0` doesn't work. An error message appeared: `mount: no mount helper program found for *vfat*: No such file or directory`. This despite the fact that `ntfs_3g` package was installed.

Comment: I added the results of `dmesg` that may be of relevance to you.

Comment: is `sd1i` the actual special file for your device? please try with `sdb1`

Comment: BSD uses `msdos` as its type for fat32, so use `-t msdos` instead.

Comment: aow that's right, I totally forgot that :D

Comment: @Bacon: `sdb1` is Linux convention. OpenBSD uses `sd1i` to mount a flash drive. On OpenBSD, one uses `sysctl hw.disknames` to find the disknames of hard drives, CD ROM drives and USB drives attached to the machine.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of rusty when it comes to OpenBSD ^^ did you try the `-t msdos` ?

Comment: @DravSloan: After issuing the command `mount -t msdos /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb0` the same error message appeared: `mount_msdos: /dev/sd1i on /mnt/usb0 : Inappropriate file type or format`

Comment: @Bacon: *Yeah I'm kind of rusty when it comes to OpenBSD ^^ did you try the -t msdos ?* The same error message `mount_msdos: /dev/sd1i on /mnt/usb0 : Inappropriate file type or format` appeared.

Comment: can you display the output of `fdisk sd1i` and `disklabel sd1i` ?